# React Application is encoding or decoding string and making it unconsumable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, redux

This is my original string that I am getting from Query Params using URLSearchParams `7Gqd+TkrOsJr/rU4Kcyl0RO6LYa9yeO4A7nx8mpFOdj2AqFzu84DoQuYzDFGZRwesCu7/PWVNSyxIQwJbktD7tcVkYic508wZC9ifHRjH8poFxRw8wbNquOsFlUcvYZXjYM1irVw0WOTPf8=`

When I access it and store it in the Redux store, it is encoded to -> `7Gqd TkrOsJr/rU4Kcyl0RO6LYa9yeO4A7nx8mpFOdj2AqFzu84DoQuYzDFGZRwesCu7/PWVNSyxIQwJbktD7tcVkYic508wZC9ifHRjH8poFxRw8wbNquOsFlUcvYZXjYM1irVw0WOTPf8=` **(The space after the first 4 characters instead of (+)**).

How do I avoid this behavior or how do I ensure the original version is stored in the string. I have tried various URIEncoding/Decodings. But doesn't seem to bring back to the exact string.

Comment: Not the storing is doing that, it's happening before that. That's base64 I guess, so it should not appear as-is in the URL in the first place but url encoded:  `7Gqd%2BTkrOsJr%2FrU4Kcyl0RO6LYa9yeO4A7nx8mpFOdj2AqFzu84DoQuYzDFGZRwesCu7%2FPWVNSyxIQwJbktD7tcVkYic508wZC9ifHRjH8poFxRw8wbNquOsFlUcvYZXjYM1irVw0WOTPf8%3D ` (this has also nothing to do with react or node or typescript or redux)

Comment: @ChrisG so what can I possibly do to fix this? Any particular method in mind?

Comment: Where's the URL coming from? You need to fix the broken code that puts base64 into the URL without encoding it first.